# Css background image not displaying in vue

Tags: css, vue.js, background-image, sidebar, hamburger-menu

I'm using `vue-burger-menu` and I'm trying to customize the background with an image but it is not displaying.

```css
.bm-burger-button{
    background-image: url('adjust.png');
}
.bm-burger-bars.line-style{
  display: none;
}
```

*adjust.png* is in the same components folder as the vue page containing the sidebar.

When I do:

```css
.bm-burger-button{
    background-color: rgba(66,147,167,1);
    border-radius: 20px;  
}
```

it shows the background as a blue circle but **when I want to use an image the image will not display**. Any ideas on how to go about this? Thanks!

**Update**

I was able to get it by adding:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Comment: Your path to the image is probably wrong. Where is your CSS? In an external style sheet? In the Vue component? All that stuff gets compiled and moved by Webpack so you should put your image where [you know the final URL](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder).

Comment: My css is in the vue component, I'm using vue-cli and the css is in style tag. This burger menu is in HelloWorld.vue which is in components folder and adjust.png is also in components folder. Thank you for the link!

Comment: My point is that once you compile the Vue project your Vue component is NO LONGER in the same folder, neither is your CSS, etc. Webpack combines, moves files, and rewrites URLs. [Vue docs for static assets](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html)

Comment: Oh now I understand, thank you for your help!